# Magento2 How to get list of products that has special price in graphql

Tags: magento2, graphql

Magento2 How can I set filter for products in order to return products that has special price

I am checking this URL but not able to figure out how to achieve this?

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/products.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if possible to use a filter with special_price attribute ?

Comment: It says Field \"special_price\" is not defined by type ProductAttributeFilterInput